# Ubuntu 16.04, too many ttys

Tags: tty, virtual-console

I'm working on a zynq board with Ubuntu 16.04. I find that there are more than 300 `/dev/tty*`.

My question is how can I reduce the number of TTYs?

[image: more than 300 ttys]

Comment: I suppose you cut the image short... I'm not too sure why you'd get `/dev/ttya[0-9a-f]` to `/dev/ttyz[0-9a-f]`. I don't have those on my system. Note that a TTY like this doesn't take much space (1 block on your HDD/SSD). Why is it that you think you should have less entries there?

Comment: What does the system log say? `journalctl -b 0`

Comment: Why do you think that the number of tty's is a problem ?

Comment: @AlexisWilke I'm trying to speed up booting time. When I run `systemd-analyze plot > a.svg`, I find that these ttys takes about 500ms. The service name is `sys-devices-virtual-tty-ttyxx.device` and `dev-ttyxx.device`

Comment: @waltinator yes, I had checked it, but i didn't find anyting about tty except for the serial port used to login. Sorry, I didn't find how to upload it here.

Comment: @SorenA Hi SorenA, I answer your question above, but I can only mention one user name in a comment.  Could you please check it?

Answer (score 0):

After I change some options in petalinux(yocto), I find what are these ttys.It consists of two parts, one is `Virtual terminal`, the other is `PTY`.

I disable `Virtual Terminal` and set number of `PTY` to 5(the default value is 256), then there are only 11 ttys in /dev.

BTW, `ssh` will failed if I just disable `PTY`.